# Bash Script, find file size and compare not running

Tags: bash, shell, find, test

Very new to bash as you will see in code below.

I want to get the file size in bytes of a file, compare that to a fixed value and send an email if the latter is too small.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=$(find /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz -ctime 0 -print -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{print $5}')

if [$f -lt 60000000000] ; then
echo "hello";
fi
```

The output of the command above is `18607414901` bytes, i.e. 18gb.

What I want is to execute command if that is less than 60gb. The `echo` command is used just to test that.

```
./backupsql.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for your `find` command (`man find`)? it likely has an option to identify files that are smaller than a given size directly.

Comment: another plug for shellcheck.net

Comment: Apart from that, since the Q was tagged with [linux], you probably have GNU find, and can get the file size with `find ... -printf "%s\n"` (no need for external `ls`). Also, as steeldriver hinted, even POSIX find has `-size` to match based on the file size.

Answer (score 0):

You need some spaces in the test:

```
if [ $f -lt 60000000000 ] ;then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `wc` command with `-c` option (*print the byte counts*) to get file size in bytes for further comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$(wc -c < /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz)
if [ $s -lt 60000000000 ]; then
echo "hello"
fi
```

---

Another way is using `stat` command with `-c` option:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$(stat -c "%s" /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz)
if [ $s -lt 60000000000 ]; then
echo "hello"
fi
```

`-c` - tells to use the specified format

`%s` - the format representing total size, in bytes

Answer (score 0):

Script? Here is a one-liner:

```
[ $(stat -c %s $(ls -tr /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz | tail -n 1)) -lt 60000000000 ] && echo "Error" | mail -s "Too small" root@example.org
```

`ls -tr /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz` will list all files in reverse order by timestamp. The last one is the newest. `tail -n 1` will show the last file. `$(..)` is the text of a command. `stat -c %s <file>` will show the size of a file. `[ ... ]` is actually the command /usr/bin/test if return code is `0` it will run the command after `&&`.

If you run this command in crontab you have to escape `%` with `\`, like `[ $(stat -c \%s ..`

The script version:

```
#! /bin/bash
LASTFILE=$(ls -tr /var/lib/xxxxxx/backups/xxxxxxxxDB*.gz | tail -n 1)
if [ $(stat -c %s $LASTFILE) -lt 60000000000 ]; then
  echo "$LASTFILE" | mail -s "Too small" root@example.org
fi
```